# How to use maven with Java9.0.1 and pom packaging in Eclipse Oxygen 1a Release (4.7.1a)?

Tags: maven, m2e, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

The maven project example that is given below shows an error in **module-info.java** in Eclipse Oxygen:

```
log4j.api cannot be resolved to a module.
```

If I remove the line

```
<packaging>pom<packaging>
```

from pom.xml the error disappears. However, I need to use pom packaging. If I use Java8 without module definitions, the maven part in my real world example works very well. Trying to migrate to Java9 confronted me with this new issue. First I thought I would not correctly reference the log4j dependency. Then I found out that is has something to do with the pom packaging that I need in my multi-module project. I created a minimal example that is given below to allow you to reproduce the error messages in Eclipse.

=>Is this a bug of the M2E plugin (1.8.2.20171007-0217)?

=>If not, how do I have to adapt my pom.xml file to work with Java9?

Related issues:

- [How to use log4j with maven and java9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47223440/how-to-use-log4j-with-maven-and-java9)
- [Import of a Java-9-Jigsaw-Maven-Project in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343741/import-of-a-java-9-jigsaw-maven-project-in-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-does-not-work)
- [Java 9 Modules and JUnit 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456826/java-9-modules-and-junit-4)
- [Can Maven generate the module declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201997/can-maven-generate-the-module-declaration)
- [Where should I put unit tests when migrating a Java 8 project to Jigsaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366582/where-should-i-put-unit-tests-when-migrating-a-java-8-project-to-jigsaw#comment69959520_41370766)
- [Which module should I require in Java 9 to use JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471927/which-module-should-i-require-in-java-9-to-use-jpa)
- List of java modules: http://download.java.net/java/jigsaw/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Min example project (my real example is more complex):

[image]

pom.xml:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Log4JWithJava9</groupId>
    <artifactId>Log4JWithJava9</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- encoding -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <!-- plugin for resource phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>resource-execution</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- plugin for compile phase (and test-compile phase) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specify current java version here: -->
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-execution</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile-execution</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- ### PACKAGE ### phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-execution</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        <!-- plugin for install phase -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-execution</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

module-info.java

```
module Log4JWithJava9 {
    exports isi.share;      
    requires javafx.base;
    requires log4j.api; 
}
```

Main.java

```
package isi.share;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class Main {

    private static Logger sysLog = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Output for maven run configuration with clean install:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Log4JWithJava9 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (resource-execution) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (compile-execution) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[WARNING] ********************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
[WARNING] ********************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (test-compile-execution) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (package-execution) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\target\Log4JWithJava9-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] Installing D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\pom.xml to C:\Users\eis\.m2\repository\Log4JWithJava9\Log4JWithJava9\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Log4JWithJava9-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (install-execution) @ Log4JWithJava9 ---
[INFO] Installing D:\EclipseJava\workspace\Log4JWithJava9\pom.xml to C:\Users\eis\.m2\repository\Log4JWithJava9\Log4JWithJava9\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Log4JWithJava9-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.520 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-10T20:41:10+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/52M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whole Eclipse example project:

https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/java9MavenEclipse

Tools used:

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, Oxygen 1a Release (4.7.1a)
(Including M2E version 1.8.2.20171007-0217)

Java JDK version 9.0.1

Comment: Well, the question also is why do you want to package pom and still use `dependencies` and not `<dependencyManagement>`? Are those dependencies used in the parent level as well? All this assuming we are talking about the same [pom packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692161/what-is-pom-packaging-in-maven).

Comment: And a weird thing in the screenshot, what is the other `src` folder doing there? And another note, the sample as shared by you in question. [Works fine for me.](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk9-mavenpomlog4j)

Comment: And what command are you executing such that you get the stated error?

Comment: a)Yes, in my real example the dependencies are used in another maven project, that references a sub project using <modules> tag. b) The src folder is the same one. It is shown twice in the Eclipse view.  c) The error can be seen after updating the Maven project in Eclipse (Alt+F5)

Comment: a. please edit the question with appropriate details... b. doesn't seem to be just a view, looks like a symlink....c. what happens if you execute `mvn clean install` on the project?

Comment: I added the output of maven and committed the example project to github.

Comment: Okay, seems specific to Eclipse you mean? Please update the complete details of the libraries and tool versions used.

Comment: First why do you manually bind the plugins to the life cycle ? Does not make sense. Use the usual jar packaging. Correctly define the compiler version

Comment: Comments like "why are you doing this" do not really help me and I would prefer if you could concentrate on the "how". As I already stated using the jar packaging would avoid the error in this minimal example but my question clearly targets the pom packaging. I did not ask "When to use pom packaging?". Nevertheless thank you for your comments. The issue might be specific to the M2E plugin of Eclipse. But I am not sure about it since I just started with Java9. If you want to help please check out the example form the linked github project.

Comment: @khmarbaise For my real world example: If I want to use modules I have to use pom packaging. The pom packaging does not include compile phase. In order to compile I bind the compile plugin. For the "min example" the reason is that I wanted to kind of simulate the jar packaging to better understand what the difference between using pom packaging or not might be. I thought the pom packaging might miss a phase that is required for the Java9 modules to work correctly.

Comment: @Stefan First let make something clear. If I'm asking why it is based the need to understand the problem first before making a suggestion for a solution. If you this will not help Ok than I can't help you. Apart from that your assumption is simply wrong. To use modules you can simply use `jar` packaging as usual. The problem you have is simply that the log4j dependencies do not contain a `module-info.class` file. They are called automatic modules which means their module name is derived from the artifact name. And that's the reason for the WARNING of the maven-compiler-plugin. (Part I)

Comment: Part II: The problems in Eclipse is related to issues related to the support of JDK 9 in Eclipse related to autonamed modules...or to m2e...
(BTW: Made a simple example project: https://github.com/khmarbaise/simple-jdk9-maven).